# Firebase cloudfunctions object can not be encoded with json android

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to pass a music file  I just reocrded to my cloud functions in firebase, yet I receieve an error every time I try to upload it:

> Object cannot be encoded in JSON: /storage/emulated/0/tempRecordFile.wav

My code:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("sound", soundFile);
    return firebaseFunctions.getHttpsCallable("soundFunction")
                            .call(data)
                            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Boolean>() {
                                @Override
                                public Boolean then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                                    return (boolean) Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getData();
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters that you pass to callable Cloud Functions must be valid JSON values. You're trying to pass a `File` as the `sound` parameter, and `File` is not a valid JSON type.

If you want to pass the file path to the Cloud Function, pass it as a string:

```
data.put("sound", soundFile.getPath());
```

---

If you want to pass the contents of the sound file to the Cloud Function, you'll have to read the contents into memory, and pass then in a JSON compatible type. This is typically done using a base-64 encoding.

---

The final option I can quickly think of, is to upload the binary data to Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK, and then pass the path to the Cloud Function as a string.

For this, see [upload data from a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) in the Firebase documentation, and then pass the [`StorageReference.getPath()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getPath()) to the Cloud Function.